# Converting a bitmap image into a byte array

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap, byte

Can you please tell me how to convert a bitmap to bytes?

Below is the code to copy a bitmap to a buffer, but how do I copy its bytes to later use? For example to reset the picture to disk, or use in memory for your application.

```
void GetScreenShot(void)
{
    int x1, y1, x2, y2, w, h;

    // get screen dimensions
    x1 = GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
    y1 = GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);
    x2 = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
    y2 = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
    w = x2 - x1;
    h = y2 - y1;

    // copy screen to bitmap
    HDC     hScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC     hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreen);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, w, h);
    HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
    BOOL    bRet = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, w, h, hScreen, x1, y1, SRCCOPY);

    // save bitmap to clipboard
    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hBitmap);
    CloseClipboard();

    // clean up
    SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);
    DeleteDC(hDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hScreen);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getbitmapbits

Comment: [`GetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject) or [`GetDIBits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdibits).

Comment: hBitmap is in a unspecified format (but probably 32-bit RGB if DWM is active). You need to ask GDI or request a conversion before you can interpret the bits.